# Converting dataframe into sub-list or dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data in tabular format (rows and columns) which I read into a dataframe (Data1) :

```
     Name         D    Score
0   Angelica     D1     3.5
1   Angelica     D2     2.0
2   Bill         D1     2.0
3   Chan         D3     1.0 
......
```

I am able to convert it into a list using:

```
Data2 = Data1.values.tolist()
```

and get the below output:

```
[
['Angelica', 'D1', 3.5], ['Angelica', 'D2', 2.0],
['Bill', 'D1', 2.0], ['Bill', 'D2', 3.5],
['Chan', 'D8', 1.0], ['Chan', 'D3', 3.0], ['Chan', 'D4', 5.0],
['Dan', 'D4', 3.0], ['Dan', 'D5', 4.5], ['Dan', 'D6', 4.0]
]
```

What I want is, the output to be like this:

```
{
'Angelica': {'D1': 3.5, 'D2': 2.0} ,
'Bill': {'D1': 2.0, 'D2': 3.5} 
'Chan': {'D8': 1.0, 'D3': 3.0, 'D4': 5.0 } 
'Dan': {'D4': 3.0, 'D5': 4.5, 'D6': 4.0} 
}
```

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: this is a dictionary not tuple

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *dictionary comprehension* after *grouping* the df by the `Name` column:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'Angela', 'Score': 3.5, 'D': 'D1'}, {'Name': 'Angela', 'Score': 2.0, 'D': 'D2'}, {'Name': 'Bill', 'Score': 2.0, 'D': 'D1'}, {'Name': 'Chan', 'Score': 1.0, 'D': 'D3'}])
>>> df
    D    Name  Score
0  D1  Angela    3.5
1  D2  Angela    2.0
2  D1    Bill    2.0
3  D3    Chan    1.0
>>> data2 = {name: {df.ix[v].D: df.ix[v].Score for v in val} for name, val in df.groupby('Name').groups.items()}
>>> data2
{'Chan': {'D3': 1.0}, 'Angela': {'D1': 3.5, 'D2': 2.0}, 'Bill': {'D1': 2.0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can zip up the values from each group after grouping by Name:

```
In [4]: l = [
   ...: ['Angelica', 'D1', 3.5], ['Angelica', 'D2', 2.0],
   ...: ['Bill', 'D1', 2.0], ['Bill', 'D2', 3.5],
   ...: ['Chan', 'D8', 1.0], ['Chan', 'D3', 3.0], ['Chan', 'D4', 5.0],
   ...: ['Dan', 'D4', 3.0], ['Dan', 'D5', 4.5], ['Dan', 'D6', 4.0]
   ...: ]
   ...: columns=["Name", "D", "Score"]
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=columns)
   ...: 

In [5]: {name: dict(zip(v["D"], v["Score"])) for name, v in df.groupby("Name")}


In [6]: data
Out[6]: 
{'Angelica': {'D1': 3.5, 'D2': 2.0},
 'Bill': {'D1': 2.0, 'D2': 3.5},
 'Chan': {'D3': 3.0, 'D4': 5.0, 'D8': 1.0},
 'Dan': {'D4': 3.0, 'D5': 4.5, 'D6': 4.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(dict)

for item in Data2:
    result[item[0]].update(dict([item[1:]]))
```